# XML generation using fprintf

Tags: c, xml, printf

When generating am xml in C by using fprintf(), what should be kept in mind?
I am using it, but i am facing some issues when opening the xml in IE; however, in any editor, it shows proper contents.

**Code**

```
int WriteXmlElement(const char* filename, const char* element, int iTextAssociated)
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;

   fp = fopen(filename, "a+");
   if(fp != NULL)
   {
      fprintf(fp, "<%s>\n",element);
      fprintf(fp,"</%s>\n" , element);

      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
   }
   else 
      return -1;

}
```

**XML in IE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Group />
```

**XML in any editor**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Group> </Group>
```

Comment: Please narrow the scope of your question. "What should I keep in mind" is very broad and could involve numerous things. Give us something to focus on.

Comment: Sure. I used two fprintf statements in my code to print <Group> and </Group> after the xml header. Now when i open my xml using IE, i see the xml header followed by <Group\>(which is wrong), whereas any editor shows proper contents.

Comment: What about showing some code and output?

Comment: Please just _edit_ your question to provide additional information, code or clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The XML is being generated just fine.  Internet Explorer is choosing to reinterpret it by automatically refactoring empty tags of the form `<foo></foo>` into just `<foo/>` for display purposes (it does not modify the file on disk).  If you want to be sure that the XML file you're generating has the proper contents, just look at it in a regular text editor instead of IE.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try adding more nodes to my parent node(Group) and then check if IE displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing is the simplest way ..but i prefer you to use http://www.minixml.org/

in your way make sure this thing
1> every node should be closed in order

2> if you are not writing anything between  &  then put one space between them
(some browser shows error if you dont write anything between that)